# Non blocking strategy for executing a pair of operations atomically in Java

Tags: java, atomic, nonblocking

Lets say I have a `Set` and another `Queue`. I want to check in the `set` if it `contains(Element)` and if not `add(element)` to the `queue`. I want to do the two steps atomically.

One obvious way is to use `synchronized` blocks or `Lock.lock()/unlock()` methods. Under thread contention , these will cause context switches.  Is there any simple design strategy for achieving this in a non-blocking manner ? may be using some Atomic constructs ?

Comment: Why should `sychronized` or `Lock` cause context switches?

Comment: It's not quite clear what does atomicity mean in this context. What are possible consequences of not doing it atomically?

Comment: @A.H., because of the way they are implemented by JVM for most platforms , if threads contend then this will cause one of them to be suspended hence a switch of context... ( AFAIK )

Comment: @axtavt , for one , an element may end up getting added into the `queue` even though the `set` already contains it ... this is undesirable

Comment: @Bhaskar: Ah, but your question does not mention the contention case, only the "right through" case IMO.

Comment: @Bhaskar: It only makes sense if adding element to the queue somehow prevents adding that element to the set, though I cannot imagine how can it happen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can rely on any mechanism, except the ones you pointed out yourself, simply because you're operating on two structures.

There's decent support for concurrent/atomic operations on *one* data structure (like "put if not exists" in a ConcurrentHashMap), but for a sequence of operations, you're stuck with either a lock or a synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

Since the *contention case* is the relevant case you should look at "spin locks". They do not give away the CPU but spin on a flag expecting the flag to be free very soon.

Note however that *real* spin locks are seldom useful in Java because the normal `Lock` is quite good. See [this blog](http://mkseo.pe.kr/blog/?p=689) where someone had first implemented a spinlock in Java only to find that after some corrections (i.e. after making the test correct) spin locks are on par with the standard stuff.

Comment: Spin locks, in general, are evil.  And most lock strategies do employ a (special case) spin lock for a very brief interval before forcing a task switch, so you tend to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @HotLicks: I concur that spin locks are not bread and butter stuff, they have sharp edges instead (more like blades indeed). But nevertheless there are occasions where they are useful and appropriate. _IF_ this is one of this cases: The TO might tell us.

Comment: Spin locks are good if you expect contention to be very low, and thus the actual amount of "spinning" to be low.  I've been able to bring an algorithm that exhibited sub-linear speedup to linear speedup by replacing the "standard" locks with spin-locks--in my case contention was expected to drop to 0 as n went to infinity.  But in general I would look at using spin-locks as an optimization--e.g. premature spin-locks are an element of the [root of all evil](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Answer (score 1):

For some operations you can employ what is called a "safe sequence", where concurrent operations may overlap without conflicting.  For instance, you might be able to add a member to a set (in theory) without the need to synchronize, since two threads simultaneously adding the same member do not conceptually conflict with each other.

But to query one object and then conditionally operate on a different object is a much more complicated scenario.  *If* your sequence was to query the set, then conditionally insert the member into the set and into the queue, the query and first insert could be replaced with a "compare and swap" operation that syncs without stalling (except perhaps at the memory access level), and then one could insert the member into the queue based on the success of the first operation, only needing to synchronize the queue insert itself.  However, this sequence leaves the scenario where another thread could fail the insert and still not find the member in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` to get the semantics you want.  They have a `putIfAbsent` that does an atomic insert.  You then essentially try to add an element to the map, and if it succeeds, you know that thread that performed the insert is the only one that has, and you can then put the item in the queue safely.  The other significant point here is that the operations on a ConcurrentMap insure "happens-before" semantics.

```
ConcurrentMap<Element,Boolean> set = new ConcurrentHashMap<Element,Boolean>();
Queue<Element> queue = ...;

void maybeAddToQueue(Element e) {
    if (set.putIfAbsent(e, true) == null) {
        queue.offer(e);
    }
}
```

Note, the actual value type (Boolean) of the map is unimportant here.

Comment: But that doesn't perform the operations atomically.  It would be possible for a second thread to get an "already there" response from the set but not find the element in the queue.

Comment: One element will be queued regardless.

Comment: Yes, but if the second thread is assuming that the element has been queued and attempts to access it then it will have problems.  It all depends on what the overall program design is, and what "contract" you're attempting to enforce.

Comment: Sure, I agree--there is a chance that another thread could observe that the element is in the set and not in the queue, but the reverse will not happen.  Usually it's not the queuing code that will observe the queue contents, but instead the dequeuing end--that's where special attention will be needed, and the question isn't (yet) concerned with that.  Also, the question is not "can this be atomically", but "is there any simple design strategy for achieving this in a non-blocking manner?"